# In Nginx can I set Keep-Alive dynamically depending on ssl connection?

Tags: nginx, keepalive, keep-alive

I would like to avoid having to repeat all the virtualhost server {} blocks in nginx just to have custom ssl settings that vary slightly from plain http requests.

Most ssl directives can be placed right in the main block, except one hurdle I cannot find a workaround for:  different keep-alive for `https` vs `http`

Is there any way I can use $scheme to dynamically change the `keepalive_timeout` ?

I've even considered that I can use `more_set_input_headers -r 'Keep-Alive: timeout=60';` 
to conditionally replace the keep-alive timeout only if it already exists, but the problem is `$scheme` cannot be used in `location` ie. this is invalid `location ^https {}`

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can use a [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) :

```
map $scheme $myCustomTTL {
   default     90;
   http        90;
   https       60;
}

add_header Keep-Alive timeout=$myCustomTTL;
```

Comment: Ohh! Didn't know about that one, it's a very basic switch/case, thank you.

Comment: This will not work. You just set a header for browser, but it will not affect nginx behavior. Clients may ignore this header.

Comment: You're right. I've just followed what @ck_ was suggesting with headers, without asking myself if it was a good practice. [`keepalive_timeout`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#keepalive_timeout) is the directive used by nginx to control the KeepAlive behavior. So what should be written is : `keepalive_timeout ${myCustomTTL}s ${myCustomTTL}s`

Comment: Actually:  `keepalive_timeout" directive invalid value in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` what I think is happening is how nginx cannot use variables during load time, only runtime.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems that `keepalive_timeout` cannot be used with parameters but only with fixed values, another solution would be to use `nginx` as a SSL endpoint.

Your SSL requests will be handled by a specific `server{}` block, that would only manage the SSL handshake and the specific `Keep-Alive` value, then forward the plain-HTTP request to the main `server {}` block.

Your `nginx` configuration would include something like the following:

```
upstream plain_http {
   server  127.0.0.1:80;
} 

server {
   listen   443;
   server_name  *.yourdomain.com;
   ssl                       on;
   ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/ssl/mycert.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/ssl/mykey.key;
   ssl_protocols             SSLv3 TLSv1;
   ssl_ciphers               ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

   keepalive_timeout 90;

   location / {
     proxy_pass              http://plain_http;
     proxy_redirect http:// https://;  
   }
}
```

The `proxy_redirect` directive tells `nginx` to rewrite URI found in `Location` and `Refresh` headers in the plain-HTTP response.

Comment: Can nginx proxy_pass to another proxy_pass? ie. daisy chain the ssl to an apache reverse proxy?

Comment: There's no reason you couldn't do that, since the plain-HTTP `nginx` server is quite independant from its SSL sibling.